# Laravel - Strange happenings on routes

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have searched online but nothing seems to match my issue.  I have a little idea of what it may be related too, but not sure.  I have a basic User CRUD.  For my routes, I am adding them in web.app but trying to prefix them with api/

When I list my routes, I can see the correct routes, here is an example of the index

```
| GET|HEAD  | api/user | user.index | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index | web,auth
```

So within web.php I have a basic resource

```
Route::resource('api/user', 'UserController');
```

Now when I hit this route, it doesnt seem to work.  So I thought it may be to do with the fact that the api.php file has an api prefix.  So within this file, I added

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
```

And now it works.  This is where it is weird though.  If I remove the initial resource from web.php, I get an authentication error.  To have it work, I need the resource within web.php and the get in api.php.

However, I can make POST calls directly to the User Controller directly within web.php

```
Route::post('api/user', 'UserController@store');
```

This works without the need to add anything within api.php.  This is where it gets weird though.  I thought it must be the api prefix, although this does not really explain why I need it in both route files.  So within web.php, I changed it to

```
Route::resource('test/user', 'UserController');
```

But once again, without anything within api.php, the GET does not work but the POST does.

Does anyone have any idea of what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Does your UserController serve both web routes and api routes? If not, you need to prefix the controller with it's relative namespace too (e.g. 'Api\UserController') so that it hits the right one.

Comment: Only using one Controller, not in an API folder.  So do API prefixes also need to be served from the API folder?

Comment: If it's the same controller, that's fine. And no, api routes don't need to be served from anywhere in particular.

Comment: Does the user controller work properly via the web routes (if you use it that way)?

Comment: The Get only works if I also have a route within api.php as well as web.php

Comment: So I think adding resource in web.php works because it's the one handling the call. So from what I can tell, everything in the web.php file works and those in api.php don't (or only "do" if they really exist elsewhere). If you add it nowhere, and list your routes, is something else (e.g. Spark / Auth) handling /user?